# Unable to see Angular implementation in the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

When I add `'ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'` in the `main.js`, my homepage become blank on loading after save. On inspecting the blank page, I am able to see the following libs and css properly loaded in the given order

**index.html**

```
<link href="assets/css/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="assets/js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-messages/1.5.8/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://gitcdn.link/repo/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.js"></script>
```

Also tried with the CDN

[image]

**main.js**

```
var app = angular.module( indexModuleName , [
  'ngRoute', 'ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'
]);
```

**controller.js**

```
app.controller('searchCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.user = {
      search: '',
    };
});
```

**applied html**

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" ng-controller="searchCtrl" >
  <input ng-model="user.search" placeholder="Search" ng-required="true">
</md-input-container>
```

**console error:**
[image]

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $$asyncCallbackProvider <- $$asyncCallback <- $animate <- $compile
```

Comment: Don't you need to include also angular messages js?

Comment: @thepio It's a part of angular-aria, so no need to add

Comment: Oh ok, didn't know that :)

Comment: No errors in console? Do not think you need 'ngMessages' as part of the module dependencies.

Comment: updated console error in the question

Comment: Where I'm missing :(

Comment: may be try removing all dependencies and start adding one by one to get the real culprit

Comment: @thepio Added angular-messages.js as well

Comment: @developer it did work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the version mismatch finally,

```
<script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

Earlier it was,

```
<script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

Fixed it by adding `bower.json` and through updating the entire libs